# Error manipulating datetime x-axis in matplotlib python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Data df is in this format:

```
    Id  Timestamp               Data    Group
0   1   2013-08-12 10:29:19.673 40.0    1
1   2   2013-08-13 10:29:20.687 50.0    2
2   3   2013-09-14 10:29:20.687 40.0    3
3   4   2013-10-14 10:29:20.687 30.0    4
4   5   2013-11-15 10:29:20.687 50.0    5
                    ...
```

I plotted the graph to observe how `Data` varies over time with code:

```
%matplotlib notebook
%matplotlib inline

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])   
df= df[(df['Timestamp'] > '2013-12-05 ') & (df['Timestamp'] <= '2013-12-30 ')]

df1 = df[df['Group'] ==1]
df1.plot(x = 'Timestamp', y = 'Data',figsize=(20, 10))
```

The graph looks fine: [image]

But when I was trying to narrow down the time interval to `2013-12-05 ~2013-12-11`(from `2013-12-05 ~2013-12-30`), with code:

```
%matplotlib notebook
%matplotlib inline

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])   
df= df[(df['Timestamp'] > '2013-12-05 ') & (df['Timestamp'] <= '2013-12-11')]

df1 = df[df['Group'] ==1]
df1.plot(x = 'Timestamp', y = 'Data',figsize=(20, 10))
```

the graph looks off as we'd expected the new graph to capture the first half of the old graph given that new time interval overlaps with the old graph in the first half of the total duration. But the graph looks like this:
[image]
The x-axis marks also no longer makes sense. What could go wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thx

Comment: Looks like `mm-dd HH` to me.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html).