# How to make a plot interactive

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The data looks like this:

```
    Id  Timestamp               Data    Group
0   1   2013-08-12 10:29:19.673 40.0    1
1   2   2013-08-13 10:29:20.687 50.0    2
2   3   2013-09-14 10:29:20.687 40.0    3
3   4   2013-10-14 10:29:20.687 30.0    4
4   5   2013-11-15 10:29:20.687 50.0    5
                    ...
```

I was able to plot a normal line graph but want to create an interactive graph using Matplotlib. I used the code:

```
%matplotlib notebook
%matplotlib inline

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])   
df1 = df[df['Group'] ==1]
plt.plot( x = 'Timestamp', y = 'Data',figsize=(20, 10))
plt.show()
```

It returned an empty graph and error

> TypeError: plot got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'

### What is wrong?

Update:
Complete Error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-0eb3ff7c9c6c> in <module>()
      9 df1 = df[df['Group'] ==1]
     10 # df1 = df.groupby(df['Group'])
---> 11 plt.plot( x = df1['Timestamp'], y = df1['Data'], figsize=(20, 10))

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    169             if pos_only in kwargs:
    170                 raise TypeError("{} got an unexpected keyword argument {!r}"
--> 171                                 .format(self.command, pos_only))
    172 
    173         if not args:

TypeError: plot got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'
```

Comment: Try changing to `x=df['Timestamp']` & `y=df['Data']`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Matplotlib is not known for its interactive graphs. please try to use plotly or bokeh for interactive graphs.

Comment: @GIRISHkuniyal Thank you for the head up. I will give it a try:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** It is solution for error message, not explanation how to create interactive plot which would need [event handling](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/event_handling.html) (Doc: [Interactive plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/interactive.html))

---

To use `x=` you would have to use `df.plot()` instead of `plt.plot()`

```
df.plot(x='Timestamp', y='Data', figsize=(20, 10))
```

If you want to use `plt.plot()` then you have to sets values without `x=`

```
plt.plot(df['Timestamp'], df['Data'])
```

because it get it as positional arguments (`*args`), not named arguments.

And it doesn't have argument `figsize=`

See arguments in documentation [matplotlib.pyplot.plot()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! You seem to be an expert in `matplotlib`, would you like to take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/59063063/11901732

Answer (score -1):

As advised by @GIRISHkuniyal, using [plotly.express](https://plot.ly/python/line-charts/) helps to make the plot interactive with code:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(df1, 'Timestamp', 'Data')
fig.show()
```

Thanks

---

Update:
Sometimes may have to run

```
def configure_plotly_browser_state():
  import IPython
  display(IPython.core.display.HTML('''
        <script src="/static/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <script>
          requirejs.config({
            paths: {
              base: '/static/base',
              plotly: 'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js?noext',
            },
          });
        </script>
        '''))
```

beforehand as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47230966/11901732) to custom initialise Plotly.

Comment: It is clearly asking for "Matplotlib". Your solution cannot be an answer even remotely. Just put it in the comments if you don't know the answer.

Comment: Hey @Ash, thanks for your comment. I asked this question thinking it was a matplotlib issue, but later realised that the problem could be solved using plotly as someone pointed out. So I documented it in case it might help someone else who had similar problems as me. It does not really matter what method is used as long as it solves the issue. And I think it's fine that I didn't clearly know the cause when I asked the question.